# angular Rxjs tap guaranteed running code section

Tags: angular, rxjs

when using tap we have 3 sections: event, error, complete.

the complete section will be triggered only if no error occurred on the way.
is there a way to guarantee that the complete section will run no matter what (like finally in exception handling)?

```
tap(ev => console.log('event: ', ev)
    err => console.log('error:', err),
    () => console.log('guaranteed section?') );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could alternatively use RxJS `finalize` operator, have a look at [Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html). **`finalize` is executed when Observable completes or errors.**

For example:

```
finalize(() => console.log('Sequence complete')) // Execute when the observable completes
```